# va_arg(argp, float) is crashing

Tags: c, avr-gcc

I'm trying to write custom printf function.

```
void debug_print(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    const char *p;
    va_list argp;
    int i;
    double f;
    char *s;
    char fmtbuf[80];

    va_start(argp, fmt);

    for(p = fmt; *p != '\0'; p++)
    {
        if(*p != '%')
        {
            uart_putchar(*p);
            continue;
        }

        switch(*++p)
        {
            case 'c':
                        ...
            break;

            case 'f':
            f = va_arg(argp, float); // ??????
            s = dtostrf(f, 10, 6, fmtbuf);
            uart_puts(s);
            break;

...
// then in the main part of the program
debug_print("%f", 123.456);
```

When program comes to f = va_arg(argp, float) it never returns from that line. If I change it to f = va_arg(argp, double) it returns 0.

Tried both on device(ATMega328P) and Atmel Studio 6 simulator, same result.

Sounds like something to do with linker options?

**UPDATE:**

Now just need to find out why `va_arg(argp, double)` returns 0.

Comment: On another note, verify whether Atmega series supports float...

Comment: I am extensively using `float` in the same program.

Comment: I have used atmega8-32 in past. I **think** it does not support float. At least the hardware does not. If the compiler does some magic, to convert the code to fixed point, I don't know. Check once with a dummy program, else you will have to convert entire program to work without floats, using fixed point maybe. Just verify it, before you continue writing further program with float.

Comment: turns out to be optimization issue. I was able to get the float number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a `float` in a variable argument list, it's implicitly promoted to a `double` by the compiler. So, you'll have to use `va_arg(argp, double)` to fetch it from the variable argument list.

When you do try to fetch the argument as a `float`, then

> `type` is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according
>   to the default argument promotions) [and] the behavior is undefined

(Standard §7.16.1.1, The `va_arg` macro. Per §6.2.7, `float` and `double` are not compatible.)

Comment: @Pablo: how do you determine that? Might there be a bug in `dtostrf`?

Comment: `0` is coming from `va_arg(argp, double)`. Not even talking about dtostrf, which works just fine. I determine that a) in debugger b) by just printing `f` after `va_arg(argp, double)`. The same does work in Visual Studio. That's why I mentioned avr-gcc so someone might have experience with it.

Comment: @Pablo: I'm not familiar with `avr-gcc`. But in any case, `float` should *not* work.

Comment: Understood with float. Anyway, I'm trying to get that bloody argument.